# htmlTable in Rmd - conversion to Word docx

Tags: ms-word, html-table, r-markdown

I have the following Rmd file, which produces an html file, which I then copy-paste into a docx file (for collaborators). Here are things I'd like to know how to do with the tables, but I can't find answers in the vignettes [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/general.html):

A. I want to know how to remove the blank column that gets inserted in Word in between Cgroup 1 and Cgroup 2.

B. I want to know how to set the width of the column with the row names ("1st row",...)

C. How can I change the font and font size? I tried following [this](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html) but it doesn't work to have output: word_document with htmlTable()

D. To ease the conversion to Word, is there a way to specify page breaks? Landscape orientation?

Thank you so much!

````
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  Gmisc::docx_document:
    fig_caption: TRUE
    force_captions: TRUE
---

Results
=======

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(htmlTable)
library(Gmisc)
library(knitr)
mx <-
  matrix(ncol=6, nrow=8)
rownames(mx) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd",
                        "3rd",
                        paste0(4:8, "th")),
                      "row")
colnames(mx) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd",
                        "3rd", 
                        paste0(4:6, "th")),
                      "hdr")

for (nr in 1:nrow(mx)){
  for (nc in 1:ncol(mx)){
    mx[nr, nc] <-
      paste0(nr, ":", nc)
  }
}

htmlTable(mx,
          cgroup = c("Cgroup 1", "Cgroup 2"),
          n.cgroup = c(2,4))

```
````

Answer (score 0):

The styling seemed to be off for the row names and it is now fixed in version 1.10.1 that you can download using the `devtools` package: `devtools::install_github("gforge/htmlTable", ref="develop")`

Regarding the styling the function allows almost any [CSS-style](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) you could image. Unfortunately it requires copy-pasting into Word and this functionality hasn't been Microsofts highest priority. You can easily adapt you example to accomodate the requiered changes using the css.cell:

```
library(htmlTable)
library(knitr)
mx <-
  matrix(ncol=6, nrow=8)
rownames(mx) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd",
                        "3rd",
                        paste0(4:8, "th")),
                      "row")
colnames(mx) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd",
                        "3rd", 
                        paste0(4:6, "th")),
                      "hdr")

for (nr in 1:nrow(mx)){
  for (nc in 1:ncol(mx)){
    mx[nr, nc] <-
      paste0(nr, ":", nc)
  }
}

css.cell = rep("font-size: 1.5em;", times = ncol(mx) + 1)
css.cell[1] = "width: 4cm; font-size: 2em;"
htmlTable(mx,
          css.cell=css.cell,
          css.cgroup = "color: red",
          css.table = "color: blue",
          cgroup = c("Cgroup 1", "Cgroup 2"),
          n.cgroup = c(2,4))
```

There is no way to remove the empty  column generated by cgroups. This was required for the table to look nice and is a conscious design choice.

Regarding page-breaks I doubt there is any elegant way for doing that. An alternative could possibly be the [ReporteRs](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/index.html) package. I haven't used it myself but it's closer integrated with Word and could possibly be a solution.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. I was able to change the font and the row width. However, the row width stops being respected with many columns, is there a way around this? I can include an example if that helps, in a separate question?